# redirect python input and output to text file

Tags: python

How can I redirect python input to in.txt and outputs to out.txt?

for example:

```py
print(input())
```

I want to read the input from the file and save the output to the file without actually changing the code.

I know I can use this code for save outputs to text file, but I don't know how can I read inputs from txt file:

```py
import sys
sys.stdout = open('output.txt','wt')
```

Comment: You can read a file by `with open('input.txt','r') as f` and retrieve the lines in a file by `lines = f.readlines()`

Comment: Are you trying to simply read the content of the file ? You can simply use 'r' as the second parameter of open(path, mode).
Here is a good resource : https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-open-function/ .
A good practice would be to use "with open(path, mode) as myFile" and then handle the results as you see fit (read, readlines...).

Comment: You try this code to redirect both input and output to text files:

'import sys
sys.stdin = open('in.txt', 'r')
sys.stdout = open('out.txt', 'wt')
print(input())'

Comment: thanks @vmicrobio . that's my answer

Answer (score 0):

I found:

for read inputs from txt file:

```py
import sys
sys.stdin = open('input.txt', 'r')
```

and print output to txt file:

```py
import sys
sys.stdout = open('output.txt','wt')
```